# Is it possible to create a type alias for multiple parameters of a multi-type-parameter class/function?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-generics

There are a number of situations (with Vue in particular) where a generic function takes 3, 4, or even 5 type parameters. I'm wondering if there is a way to create a type alias for that list of parameters, so I don't have to write them all out every time. I'm imagining something like:

```
// Generic function with multiple type parameters
function verboseGenericFunc<T, U, V extends T>(thing: T): V {
  // Do stuff with T, U, V
  return thing as V;
};

// Alias for the tuple of types implementing the required parameter interfaces
type VerboseTypeParams = [ConcreteT, ConcreteU, ConcreteV];

// Spread the alias to satisfy all the type parameters
const v = verboseGenericFunc<...VerboseTypeParams>(thing);
```

Comment: AFAIK nothing like this exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a type object that is an alias for the type arguments passed into the templated function. It evaluates to undefined if the wrong geenric types are passed in when creating the type alias

```
 type VerboseTypeParams<T,U,V> = V extends T? {"T":T, "U":U, "V":V}: undefined

 type concrete = VerboseTypeParams<string,number, string>; //evaluates to type we want
```

Then you can extract the types from the type alias object in a wrapper function.

```
// Generic function wrapper
function verboseGenericFunc(thing: concrete["T"] ):concrete["V"] {
  return verboseGenericFuncVue<concrete["T"],concrete["U"],concrete["V"]>(thing);
};
```

The wrapper function calls the actual function you want underneath and it doesn't need to receive any type arguments when called. If you create an incompatible wrapper or pass in the wrong type to the correct wrapper function typescript will complain.

```
// Generic function with multiple type parameters, from Vue for example
function verboseGenericFuncVue<T, U, V extends T>(thing: T): V {
  // Do stuff with T, U, V
  return thing as V;
};

type concreteBad = VerboseTypeParams<string,number, number>; //evaluates to undefined

// Bad Generic function wrapper, Typescript complains on the key lookups since concrete bad is undefined
function verboseGenericFuncBad(thing: concreteBad["T"] ):concreteBad["V"] {
  return verboseGenericFuncVue<concreteBad["T"],concreteBad["U"],concreteBad["V"]>(thing);
};

const v1 = verboseGenericFunc("1"); //correct call to wrapped function, no types passed
const v2 = verboseGenericFunc(1); //typescript complains since you're not passing in a string as expected by concrete
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=118&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAalATgIwPYGcoBVJQAoCGiBAtugDxYA0AqlXAHwwC88MUAHiFAHYAm6GFgD8MAN4AiLBIBc1GBJqy6CuLLgBfGTACu-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-ihgAjC4YZ-miAHWhImESCh6GthkABMOG-ua-6Ysc5KYQWsyvI2gQtm2JAdl2MQzrAYCoDoADkjgwDwqCtu86DTvEy66jEAQynKELQCcW7IEOmZAA)

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as MacD's answer but with slightly different execution: just use the helper type as the type parameter for your functions.

```
type TypeInfo<T = any, U = any, V extends T = any> = { T: T, U: U, V: V };

// Generic function with multiple type parameters
function verboseGenericFunc<TI extends TypeInfo>(thing: TI['T']): TI['V'] {
  // Do stuff with T, U, V
  return thing as TI['V'];
};

// Alias for the tuple of types implementing the required parameter interfaces
type VerboseTypeParams = TypeInfo<number, string, 5>;

// Spread the alias to satisfy all the type parameters
const v: 5 = verboseGenericFunc<VerboseTypeParams>(12020);

// One-off type.
const w: 'hi' = verboseGenericFunc<TypeInfo<string, null, 'hi'>>('hello');
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)